# How to know if my message is successfully delivered to a XMPP server?

Tags: xmpp

I am using Openfire and iOS XMPPFramework here. I know the existence of XEP-0184, but that's not what I am asking. I want to know if the Openfire server has successfully received my message (my message is successfully sent), so far when I send a message to the openfire server the server does not respond with anything, so I don't know if the message successfully went through or not. Can someone who is good at the XMPPFramework give me some example codes on:

1. asking the server to return a receipt when the server receives the message
2. process the receipt that's sent back from the server

My instinct told me the id attribute might be what I am looking for here, but I couldn't find relevant information online.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only standardized solution would be [XEP-198: Stream Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html), which provides stream level acknowledgements for stanzas between client and server (and s2s). [Openfire does not (yet) support Stream Management: OF-446.](https://igniterealtime.org/issues/browse/OF-446)

Other then that, XMPP has no (standardized) method of receipts send by a server to client once he has received the stanza. Note that this is different from [XEP-184: Message Delivery Receipts](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html), which provides end-to-end receipts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I would have to write some custom plugins to mimic xep 198. I will accept the solution right now.

Comment: @Alex. Were you successful in using XEP198? Did you use this [piece of Code from XMPPFramework for iOS](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0198)

Comment: I did not use xep 198 since my server doesn't support it.